# SUM of a query sql column at dataservice wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

here is the sql query and it does not accept the sum on dataservice wso2

```
SELECT nom, SUM(note) as totalnote from etudiant where nom =?;
```

when i test i get this error :

```
  <axis2ns4:ds_code>DATABASE_ERROR</axis2ns4:ds_code>
  <axis2ns4:nested_exception>java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() or executeLargeUpdate() for SELECTs</axis2ns4:nested_exception>
```

Comment: Hi Rania, can you show how you call the dataservice? Also, I do not think the SUM is actually summing anything without any grouping or subquery. But I do not think that causes the problem

Comment: Could you add the solution/share what the problem was? That way the question/answer remain valuable  for other SO users.

Comment: Yes just i added in outputmapping   ```    <result element="etudiants" rowName="etudiant">
      <element name="nom" column="nom" xsdType="STRING" />
      <element name="totalnote" column="totalnote" xsdType="INTEGER" />
    </result> ```